# Reshape the Pandas dataframe based on a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I need to 'reshape' a dataframe based on a list in a particular column, for example (see below), I need to reshape a list in the last column to have only `k` elements in a single row. For `k = 2`

```
df = 

   c1  c2  c3           c4
  aa   bb  cc  [1,2,3,4,5]
```

need to arrive at:

```
df_1 = 

  c1   c2   c3     c4
  aa   bb   cc  [1,2]
  aa   bb   cc  [3,4]
  aa   bb   cc    [5]
```

Of course it is possible to implement via loops and appending new data frames, but I am interested in more Pandasian way of implementing, as my data set is quite large. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, working with a `pd.Series` of lists is not '*pandasian*' in the first place

Comment: @RafaelC, Thank you for your comment, but I brought an abstract example to make it easier to communicate the problem I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df.c4.str.len()))# reindex to flatten your dataframe 
df.c4=df.c4.iloc[0]# assign the list value to one column
df
Out[334]:
   c1  c2  c3  c4
0  aa  bb  cc   1
0  aa  bb  cc   2
0  aa  bb  cc   3
0  aa  bb  cc   4
0  aa  bb  cc   5
df['key']=np.arange(len(df))//2# k=2

df.groupby(['c1','c2','c3','key']).c4.agg(lambda x : tuple(x.tolist()))# groupby get the expected output 
Out[352]: 
c1  c2  c3  key
aa  bb  cc  0      (1, 2)
            1      (3, 4)
            2        (5,)
Name: c4, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid lists in series wherever possible. You can instead create multiple columns:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

n = 2
A = df.pop('c4').iloc[0]
L = [(i, j) for i, j in zip_longest(A[::2], A[1::2], fillvalue=np.nan)]

res = pd.concat([df]*len(L), ignore_index=True).join(pd.DataFrame(L))

print(res)

   c1  c2  c3  0    1
0  aa  bb  cc  1  2.0
1  aa  bb  cc  3  4.0
2  aa  bb  cc  5  NaN
```